# What does the [type] mean in typescript/flow?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-typings, flowtype

I've recently stumbled upon an old code of mine, I noticed I had incorrect typing there.

```
interface OptionType {
   label: string,
   value: OptionValueType
}

interface Props {
  options: [OptionType] // < this is wrong
}
```

Now obviously, this should have been `OptionType[]` or `Array<OptionType>`, but curiously enough, the code here, at least according to both linter ([eslint](/questions/tagged/eslint)) and compiler is valid syntax.

**So, what exactly does `[OptionType]` represent?**

*My best guess would be an index/element of an array, akin to destructuring, but that feels odd as there's no original array reference in the syntax*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a tuple. It's syntax allows you to specify an array with *exactly* n elements, and give a type for each:

```
const myTuple: [string, number] = ['foo', 5];
```

Comment: Ooh got it. Out of curiosity, would you ever say there's a practical usage of tuple in actual code? I can't think of any, only cases being, where it seems to even remotely apply it seems type assertion is even more explicit eg. `property1: 'part-time' | 'full-time' | null` - I know these two are not the same thing, but I can't think of a limited array with set type of each element in practical usage. I guess closest I could think to is some sort of grouping abstraction for repeating object type.

Comment: I've used it when a function returns an x-y coordinate as a `[x, y]` tuple with the type `[number, number]`. Granted, this could be changed to an object `{ x: number, y: number }`, but this was existing code and it didn't provide any benefit to rewrite the entire application to use a different convention.

Comment: @Rawrplus one example, in a past finance-related product I built, I decided to store quantities in a `[string, string]` tuple. The first is a number (encoded as string) and the second the currency.